# Python invalid syntax on a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax

I am very new to coding so I hope my question makes sense/is formatted correctly.

Here is my code:

```
#this function takes a name and a town, and returns it as the following:
#"Hello. My name is [name]. I love the weather in [town name]." 

def introduction("name","town"):
    phrase1='Hello. My name is '
    phrase2='I love the weather in '
    return ("phrase1" + "name" + "phrase2" + "town")
```

E.g. `introduction("George","Washington")` in the python shell would return as `"Hello. My name is George. I love the weather in Washington."`

My problem is that my code is not doing that. Instead I get the following error:

```
Invalid syntax: <string> on line 1". In Wing101 **,"town"):
```

has a red swiggle under it. I'm not sure what I did wrong...I know "name" and "town" are strings and not variables, but I really have no idea how to fix it.

Any help/comments are appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you do some basic research on how to define functions, such as by reading [the relevant section in the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Comment: Will do, thank you for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use string literals as function arguments, no. You can only use variable names. Remove all the double quotes:

```
def introduction(name, town):
    phrase1='Hello. My name is '
    phrase2='. I love the weather in '
    return (phrase1 + name + phrase2 + town)
```

You pass in strings when calling the function:

```
introduction("George", "Washington")
```

and these then get assigned to `name` and `town` respectively.

Comment: Ahhh, I have so much to learn! Thank you so much for your help.